# How to run docker in jenkins blue ocean pipeline without root and run the container as our virtual environment

Tags: jenkins

I am just starting out using jenkins and having problem with the $PATH of it, so I decided to write my own docker image as an environment to use in it. Here is my Jenkinsfile that used to test if it works:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image: custom-alpine-nodejs:latest
      -p 3000:3000
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        // this return root instead of user which i created in my image
        // the image i build, run locally and enter whoami output
        // the user that i created in the image as expected, except inside jenkins
        sh 'whoami'

        // doing nvm install 8.11.2 result in nvm not found
        // but running the image i build locally works just fine
        sh 'nvm install 8.11.2' // not work
        nvm install 8.11.2 // tested this also not work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my nodejs.Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN adduser -D -g "" jenkins-runner && \
  touch /home/jenkins-runner/.bashrc /home/jenkins-runner/.profile /home/jenkins-runner/.zshrc &&\
  chown -R jenkins-runner:jenkins-runner /home/jenkins-runner && \
  apk -q update && \
  apk -q add git curl bash

USER jenkins-runner

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash && \
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && \
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

My Dockerfile runs as expected when doing it local, I can run the container and do `nvm install` and `whoami` will return `jenkins-runner`, everything just work as expected except in jenkins.

This is just one of my Dockerfile, I have prepared nodejs.Dockerfile, meteor.Dockerfile, flask.Dockerfile, elixir.Dockerfile, go.Dockerfile which prepare them for my future stuff when I do CI when them and they look just similiar.

If no solution to this, I would also be appreciate if someone could tell me how to be inside jenkins and I could be treating the environment just like my linux machine however I want and also non-root with just bare minimum of what I need to be able to run my app for testing or ci/cd.

I am using jenkins blue ocean plugin btw.